# Upload files with multi-part data using background transfer service in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-transfer

Is there any Way/Solution to upload file Multi-part data using background transfer service in windows phone 8.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20000831/1230188 & http://sportstoday.us/technology/Windows-Phone-8---Multitasking---Background-Transfer-Service.aspx

Comment: this link is using HttpClient  and HttpWebRequest methods but i need to use background transfer service of windows 8.

Comment: Did you check http://sportstoday.us/technology/Windows-Phone-8---Multitasking---Background-Transfer-Service.aspx ?

Comment: I did explore it still I am not getting to upload multipart data with background service and add headers with request. how to do it.