# Upload image and string via HTTP POST windows phone 8.1 with HttpClient

Tags: c#, django, http, post, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone application in C#. I am trying send a image (byte[]) and a session token (string) to my django server, but not how to do it.

I 've looked at other post but it does not work what they do , or classes that use do not exist.

The header of my function is:

```
    public static async Task<bool> sendImagePerfil(string token, byte[] imagen)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", token));
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("image", Convert.ToString(imagen)));

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("MyURL.domain/function", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }


    }
```

EDITED: My problem now is my server don't get the image. The django code is:

```
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RestrictedFileField(request.POST, request.FILES)
        token = models.UsuarioHasToken.objects.get(token=parameters['token'])
        user = token.user
        print (request.FILES['image'])
        user.image = request.FILES['image']
```

I can't modify the django code because this code it's working with Android app

Comment: Post your complete method implementation and state what the error is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this response ,

[How to upload file to server with HTTP POST multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data?rq=1)

Try with this...

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        form.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");

        var imageForm = new ByteArrayContent(imagen, 0, imagen.Count());
        imagenForm.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");

        form.Add(imagenForm, "image", "nameholder.jpg");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("your_url_here", form);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        httpClient.Dispose();
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Nice guy, this is the solution :)

Comment: But if the image needs to be in Base64 string this wont work!

Comment: Can you update your sample more specifically? @PaytoN