# How to upload image to server (using POST) which return json in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: json, windows-phone-8.1, image-uploading

I am making an app which can upload image to a server (the server works well), and I use this method to upload my image to it, but when I get the respond from the result, it return a null string, can you explain for me what did I do wrong.

I followed this method: [How to upload file to server with HTTP POST multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data?lq=1)

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
byte[] bytes = await Converter.GetBytesAsync(storageFile);
form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes, 0, bytes.Count()), "\"upload-file\"", "\"test.jpg\"");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("my-url", form);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
httpClient.Dispose();
string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Debug.WriteLine("res: " + sd); // this return a null string
```

The request return like this:

--a81d2efe-5f2e-4f84-83b9-261329bee20b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload-file"; filename="test.jpg"; filename*=utf-8''%22test.jpg%22

����Ivg?�aEQ�.�����(��9%�=��>�C�~/�QG$�֨������(�`������QE��Z��

Can you help me please!

P/s: Here is my convert method

```
        public static async Task<byte[]> GetBytesAsync(StorageFile file)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = null;
            if (file == null) return null;
            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
                using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
                {
                    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                    reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
                }
            }
            return fileBytes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
 private async Task<string> UploadImage(StorageFile file)
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                HttpContent content = new StringContent("fileToUpload");
                form.Add(content, "fileToUpload");
                var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
                content = new StreamContent(stream);
                content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "fileToUpload",
                    FileName = file.Name
                };
                form.Add(content);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("my-url", form);
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
```

Comment: "fileToUpload" is file to bytes or to Base64string?

Comment: I hope that is just a name. Actual content of the file is  content = new StreamContent(stream); that you will be adding to  form.Add(content);

Comment: Why "hope", it means you did not use it?

Comment: Nope. I said in answer "it might help"

Comment: I cant test whether it works or not. OpenStreamForReadAsync() method is there in System.IO namespace. You have to add that namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but maybe I need more supports, howerver, thank you!!

Comment: You want image to send in bytes or base64String?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108907/discussion-between-iamatsundere181-and-archana).

Answer (score 0):

Use ByteArrayContent instead of StringContent. That Should work.
And if you are expecting a stream-response you should use ReadAsStreamAsync instaed of ReadAsStringAsync.