# HttpClient.PostAsync without await in VS 2010

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpclient

This is a follow-up to this question:

[How to upload file to server with HTTP POST multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data)

It seems to be a good solution that uploads multipart form data. The library is available in VS 2010 through NuGet.

However, the code below uses `await` keyword, which is unavailable in VS 2010.

What would be a correct equivalent of that code without using `await`?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

form.Add(new StringContent(username), "username");
form.Add(new StringContent(useremail), "email");
form.Add(new StringContent(password), "password");
form.Add(new StringContent(usertype), "user_type");
form.Add(new StringContent(subjects), "subjects");
form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imagebytearraystring, 0, imagebytearraystring.Count()), "profile_pic", "hello1.jpg");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("PostUrl", form);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
httpClient.Dispose();
string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Same thing you did for the reaponse content `HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("PostUrl", form).Result`

Comment: HttpClient is new to .NET 4.5, Visual studio 2010 does not use .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 6):

Do the same thing you did for the response content

```
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("PostUrl", form).Result;
```

Comment: Hi Nkosi, I am also using the same code without await keyword. It serves more than 400K users. But sometimes it gets this exception. What causes this? Have any idea? : System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.