# C# multipart/form-data Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream

Tags: c#, http-post, multipartform-data

i have a problem during recive of multipart/form-data POST request, but i can't fuond a problem inside my Body. After send request, server response me With this error

> Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not
>   complete.

Follow the Body of the request.

```
-------BoundaryNg6f698dj968io34abg32rfa3

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"; filename="json"; Content-Type:application/json

{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value","key":"value","key":"value"}

-------BoundaryNg6f698dj968io34abg32rfa3

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="style"; filename="style.css"; Content-Type:text/css

body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    [etc etc]}


-------BoundaryNg6f698dj968io34abg32rfa3

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="play_circle"; filename="play_circle.png"; Content-Type:image/png


[Image]

-------BoundaryNg6f698dj968io34abg32rfa3
```

in my opinion all the body seems to be correct but i'm tired, maybe some one can help me with my problem?

@edit

Follow you can see how i build the multypart Body:

this part build the Css and Json Part.

```
public byte[] bodyBuilder()
        {
            byte[] bodyAtt = new byte[1];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PostData p in postData)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\r\n{0}", boundary));
                sb.AppendLine("\r\n");
                sb.Append(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"; Content-Type:{2}", p.Name,p.FileName, p.Type));
                sb.AppendLine("\r\n");
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}\r\n", p.Value));
            }

            bodyAtt = encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
            if (content_Type.Contains("multipart/form-data"))
            {
                bodyAtt = Combine(bodyAtt, setAttachPostData());
            }

            var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bodyAtt);

            string pathFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Log.txt");
            File.WriteAllText(pathFile, str);

            return bodyAtt;
        }
```

This is for the image.

```
public byte[] setAttachPostData()
        {

            byte[] bodyAtt = new byte[1];

            foreach (PostDataParam p in postDataParams)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("\r\n");
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}", boundary));
                sb.AppendLine("\r\n");
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"; Content-Type:{2}", p.Name, p.FileName, p.Type));
                sb.AppendLine("\r\n");
                bodyAtt = Combine(bodyAtt, encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));                     bodyAtt = Combine(bodyAtt, p.data);
            }
            bodyAtt = Combine(bodyAtt, encoding.GetBytes(string.Format("\r\n\r\n{0}\r\n", boundary)));

            return bodyAtt;
        }
```

and the combine method is simply :

```
 public static byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
        {
            byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: How are you generating this? How are you attempting to parse it? Need more details please.

Comment: This is the "String" conversion of stream. Now i update post.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using this part of code:

```
public async Task<string> BuildMultipartAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                foreach (PostData p in postData)
                {
                    form.Add(new StringContent(p.Value), p.Name, p.FileName);
                }

                foreach (PostDataParam p in postDataParams)
                {
                    form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(p.data, 0, p.data.Length), p.Name, p.FileName);
                }

                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URLCall, form);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                httpClient.Dispose();
                string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return sd;
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
```

referenced from :

> [How to upload file to server with HTTP POST multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data)

Hope can help.