# Pass encrypted byte array to web API as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, encryption, byte, aes

**Overview:**

- I have a Outlook desktop add-in *(extension)* from which user can
  browse attachment.
- We call web API(c#) to upload that attachment data into azure blob storage.
- But I want that data to be encrypted *(using AES with key and IV)* into Outlook itself *(That's working properly)* and then pass to web API.

**Questions:**

1. I tried passing data as a [CryptoStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream?view=netframework-4.8) object. But It's not
   allowing to read CryptoStream. Is that possible to pass CryptoStream
   to web api ?
2. Secondly I tried passing data as a `byte[]` (Byte Array) object. but
   that's again encrypted byte array. While `HttpPostRequest` to API
   model validation fails. Is that possible to pass encrypted byte
   array to web api.

**HttpPostRequest:**

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 content.Add(new StringContent(encryptionKey.ToString()), nameof(ChannelMessageFilePostModel.EncryptionKey).ToCamelCase());
 content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(encryptedBytes), nameof(ChannelMessageFilePostModel.EncryptedBytes).ToCamelCase());
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"ControllerName/MethodName/{id}");
 request.Content = content;

 return InvokeApi<ChannelMessageFileModel>(request, cancellationToken);
```

**Post method Web API:**

```
public async Task < IActionResult > Post(string Id, FilePostModel model) {
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) || model == null) {
  return BadRequest();
 }

 //todo: check that ModelState is working for array
 if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
  return BadRequest(ModelState);
 }
}
}
```

Here It fails on `ModelState` for `model.encryptedBytes` that is type of `byte[]`.

Comment: Can't you base64_encode that stream/bytes and pass that to the API? Also please limit the questions down to one specific issue you are facing. To answer your questions, #1 - no, #2 - yes and #3 - IMHO it's opinionated and varies depending on setup and configurations.

Comment: Base-64 encode the encrypted bytes.

Comment: Option 2 should just work and is the most efficient. Why it fails, totally depends on what you have configured your client to send and your API to receive. If you send it as form-data, you can just send binary data, no need for base64. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload. Show relevant code if you want #2 solved.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have added code of post request

Comment: @KennethK., I found ways to convert to Base64String only, Should I convert byte[] to base64 - encoded bytes[] ?

Comment: So how does that code fail? Looks good to me.

Comment: So show what your receive... Show the actual model error... Show what actually gets sent, for example using Fiddler...