# Flurl post data

Tags: flurl, processmaker

I have a processmaker web entry form and want to post data to it.
request should be like this
[image]

My code is like this:

```
var ticket = "https://xxx.yyyy.zzz"
            .AppendPathSegment("/sysworkflow/en/neoclassic/3498535156074b324397243068854136/8211975096074b37b513794064716441Post.php")
            .PostJsonAsync(new
            {
                form = new
                {
                    contract_expert = "xxxxx",
                    vendor_id = "1111",
                    vendor_name = "aaa",
                    contract_number = "bbB",
                    contract_title = "ccc"
                }
            })
            .ReceiveString().Result;
```

The problem is when I call this data with postman data will sit in their place but with flurl everything is empty after submit data. btw postman `content-type` is `multipart/form-data`

Comment: well, I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data instead of flurl for workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` != JSON, so don't use `PostJsonAsync`. Use `PostMultipartAsync`. This is documented [here](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/). Here's the relevant change to what you have:

```
.PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp.AddStringParts(new
{
    contract_expert = "xxxxx",
    vendor_id = "1111",
    vendor_name = "aaa",
    contract_number = "bbB",
    contract_title = "ccc"
}))
```