# C# - Making API request to send specific file format with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, upload

I need to send exactly **PNG** image to the server (by FormData). The request was sent successfully but the response indicated that "**Wrong file format**" (I don't have the right to access the server to check what is going on).

I'm currently using `.NET 6`

```c#
private async Task RequestApiRegister(string bookingId, string name)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Config.TOKEN_REGISTER);

    try
    {
        string aliasId = bookingId + "__" + name;
        using FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(_filePath); // --> Absolute file path, ex: "E:\\Blabla\\IMG\\image_2023_03_24T19_54_30_9573981.png"

        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        formData.Add(new StringContent("secret"), "organization");
        formData.Add(new StringContent(aliasId), "aliasId");
        formData.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "images[]", Path.GetFileName(_filePath));

        string url = "https://some-endpoint.com/register";
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);
        //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

I have spent hours searching SO but haven't found any answers yet. Here is some I have tried.

- [C# HttpClient 4.5 multipart/form-data upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)
- [How to upload file to server with HTTP POST multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data)
- More but I don't remember, sorry

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging, I managed to fix this one.

```c#
pprivate async Task RequestApiRegister(string bookingId, string name)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Config.TOKEN_REGISTER);

    try
    {
        string aliasId = bookingId + "__" + name;
        
        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_filePath);
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
        
        // This line below makes different!
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        
        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { new StringContent("internal-dev"), "organization" },
            { new StringContent(aliasId), "aliasId" },
            { fileContent, "images[]", Path.GetFileName(_filePath) }
        };

        string url = "https://some-endpoint.com/register";
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);
        //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```