# Send Multipart Form Data from c# client through nginx upload server to ASP.NET Service

Tags: c#, nginx, mime-types, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to store images from a C# client in a Nginx server using the [nginx upload module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) .

I have set up the Nginx as a Docker container and connected it over a network to an ASP.NET Core service in another Docker and an Echo service in a Docker to intercept requests to the Nginx and from the Nginx to the ASP.NET service.

This works with files sent via curl, but files from the C# client are not processed correctly and the Nginx sends an empty request via Proxy_Pass to the ASP.NET service, which then rejects it.

#### nginx config (mostly default):

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_upload_module.so;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

events {

}


http {

    server {

        listen 80;

        # Allow file uploads max 1024M for example
        client_max_body_size 1024M;
        upload_buffer_size 10M;

        # POST URL
        location /Upload {
            # Pass altered request body to this location
            upload_pass @after_upload;
            # upload_pass_args on;

            # Store files to this directory
            # upload_store /tmp/nginx_upload/;
            upload_store /upload/;
            # Allow uploaded files to be world readable
            upload_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;

            # Set specified fields in request body
            upload_set_form_field upload_file_name "$upload_file_name";
            upload_set_form_field upload_content_type "$upload_content_type";
            upload_set_form_field upload_tmp_path "$upload_tmp_path";

            # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
            upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
            upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";

            upload_pass_form_field "^submit$|^description$";
            upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
        }

        location @after_upload {
            # proxy_pass http://commoditytracker;
            proxy_pass http://echo:8080;
            # add_header Content-Type "text/plain;charset=utf-8";
            # return 200 "Upload succeeded";
        }

        root /upload;

        location / {
            root /upload;
        }

        location /upload {
            alias /upload/;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Client code

building the Form Data (here with a test image):

```
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            string path = @"C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.jpg";
            byte[] bytes = new byte[8] { 0x40, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

                bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            }

            var fileName = "test.jpg";
            var contentType = "image/jpeg"; 


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("boundary1234"))
                {
                    content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes), "file", $"{fileName}");

                    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> b = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                    var requestParameters = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("basketId", Guid.Empty.ToString());
                    b.Add(requestParameters);
                    var addMe = new FormUrlEncodedContent(b);

                    content.Add(addMe);
                    var Message = await client.PostAsync($"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8081/upload", content);
                    Console.WriteLine(Message.StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(await Message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("boundary1234"))
                {
                    content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes), "file", $"{fileName}");

                    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> b = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                    var requestParameters = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("basketId", Guid.Empty.ToString());
                    b.Add(requestParameters);
                    var addMe = new FormUrlEncodedContent(b);

                    content.Add(addMe);
                    var Message = await client.PostAsync($"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Upload", content);
                    Console.WriteLine(Message.StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(await Message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    // NavigationManager.NavigateTo("fetchdata");
                }
            }
```

#### Resulting requests

Original request from client received by echo service:

```
{
    "path": "/upload",
    "headers": {
        "host": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8081",
        "content-type": "image/jpeg",
        "content-length": "962"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "body": "--boundary1234\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=test.jpg; filename*=utf-8''test.jpg\r\n\r\n[...]\r\n--boundary1234\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data\r\n\r\nbasketId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\r\n--boundary1234--\r\n",
    "fresh": false,
    "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ip": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ips": [],
    "protocol": "http",
    "query": {},
    "subdomains": [],
    "xhr": false,
    "os": {
        "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "connection": {}
}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - - [16/Jul/2023:10:40:26 +0000] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"
```

Proxy request after nginx processed the request received by echo service:

```
{
    "path": "/Upload",
    "headers": {
        "host": "echo:8080",
        "connection": "close",
        "content-length": "108",
        "x-real-ip": "10.0.0.2",
        "x-forwarded-for": "10.0.0.2",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "x-forwarded-ssl": "on",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-original-uri": "/Upload",
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"boundary1234\"",
        "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=test.jpg"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "body": "--\"boundary1234\"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"<ngx_upload_module_dummy>\"\r\n\r\n\r\n--\"boundary1234\"--\r\n",
    "fresh": false,
    "hostname": "echo",
    "ip": "10.0.0.2",
    "ips": [
        "10.0.0.2"
    ],
    "protocol": "https",
    "query": {},
    "subdomains": [],
    "xhr": false,
    "os": {
        "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "connection": {}
}
10.0.0.2 - - [16/Jul/2023:10:40:27 +0000] "POST /Upload HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
```

#### Curl result for comparison:

Original request from client received by echo service:

`PS C:\Users\User\Downloads>  curl -X 'POST' 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx:8081/Upload?basketId=05aa7960-3f4a-42f4-8112-c22b5f96a9b5' -H 'accept: multipart/form-data' -F "upload_file_name=@$(pwd)/test.jpg"`

```
{
    "path": "/Upload",
    "headers": {
        "host": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx:8081",
        "user-agent": "curl/8.0.1",
        "accept": "multipart/form-data",
        "content-length": "877",
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------46a959572bae9574"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "body": "--------------------------46a959572bae9574\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_file_name\"; filename=\"test.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n[...]\r\n--------------------------46a959572bae9574--\r\n",
    "fresh": false,
    "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ip": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ips": [],
    "protocol": "http",
    "query": {
        "basketId": "05aa7960-3f4a-42f4-8112-c22b5f96a9b5"
    },
    "subdomains": [],
    "xhr": false,
    "os": {
        "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "connection": {}
}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - - [16/Jul/2023:11:10:05 +0000] "POST /Upload?basketId=05aa7960-3f4a-42f4-8112-c22b5f96a9b5 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/8.0.1"
```

Proxy request after nginx processed the request received by echo service:

`PS C:\Users\User\Downloads>  curl -X 'POST' 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Upload?basketId=05aa7960-3f4a-42f4-8112-c22b5f96a9b5' -H 'accept: multipart/form-data' -F "upload_file_name=@$(pwd)/test.jpg"`

```
10.0.0.2 - - [16/Jul/2023:11:07:05 +0000] "POST /Upload HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
{
    "path": "/Upload",
    "headers": {
        "host": "echo:8080",
        "connection": "close",
        "content-length": "653",
        "x-real-ip": "10.0.0.2",
        "x-forwarded-for": "10.0.0.2",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "x-forwarded-ssl": "on",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-original-uri": "/Upload?basketId=05aa7960-3f4a-42f4-8112-c22b5f96a9b5",
        "user-agent": "curl/8.0.1",
        "accept": "multipart/form-data",
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------069346ec29b44fc6"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "body": "--------------------------069346ec29b44fc6\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_file_name\"\r\n\r\ntest.jpg\r\n--------------------------069346ec29b44fc6\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_content_type\"\r\n\r\nimage/jpeg\r\n--------------------------069346ec29b44fc6\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_tmp_path\"\r\n\r\n/upload/0002424835\r\n--------------------------069346ec29b44fc6\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_file_name.md5\"\r\n\r\n77eb043e0f79321adf635dc9d9895b00\r\n--------------------------069346ec29b44fc6\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_file_name.size\"\r\n\r\n679\r\n--------------------------069346ec29b44fc6--\r\n",
    "fresh": false,
    "hostname": "echo",
    "ip": "10.0.0.2",
    "ips": [
        "10.0.0.2"
    ],
    "protocol": "https",
    "query": {
        "basketId": "05aa7960-3f4a-42f4-8112-c22b5f96a9b5"
    },
    "subdomains": [],
    "xhr": false,
    "os": {
        "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "connection": {}
}
10.0.0.2 - - [16/Jul/2023:11:08:37 +0000] "POST /Upload?basketId=05aa7960-3f4a-42f4-8112-c22b5f96a9b5 HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "curl/8.0.1"
```

My guess is that the C# client is creating invalid MultipartFormData and therefore Nginx is not processing it correctly, but why? Everything C# does for the request is hidden in the `MultipartFormDataContent`.

Expected behavior:

- Client creates MultipartFormData with given image
- nginx saves image
- nginx sends metadata to ASP.Net Server

Tried:

- Successfully Post image as MultipartFormData using curl (Expected behavior)
- Changes in C# Client:

  - Manually set content type (nginx rejects it)
  - Escape file and file name (no difference)
  - Set manual boundary (no difference)
  - Manually define `Content-Disposition` (no difference)

---

I tried the (somewhat hacky) solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/29118333/22235181, where the Form Data is manually combined and it worked. I'm using this solution, but I'm still curious why MultipartFormDataContent and Nginx-upload don't play along.

Comment: Content Type should be multipart/mixed.  Mime is the body of the request/response and each multipart attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.  See following for sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)  The body can contain combination of Mime attachments and regular body data.

Comment: When I try to set the content type with `content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/mixed");`, Nginx rejects the request with `415 Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: Does look like nginx accept multipart/mixed : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/